# How to ensure a file is only processed once in a build

Tags: c++

Is there a way to throw an error if a source file is processed multiple times in a build? I know you can use `#pragma once` and `#ifndef` type of things but that only guards it against being included in a single compilation unit once. I want to ensure it is included/compiled only once across a whole build with multiple projects in a solution in Visual Studio.

I understand that a normal .cpp file is only processed once typically. But if other files `#include`d that .cpp file, it could be processed multiple times (I know that's not typical, but it best explains the situation). So, I'm trying to guard against accidental multiple includes of the file.

Comment: _"if other files #included that .cpp file"_ that would be terribly wrong, because it's a `cpp` file. Did you mean a header (e.g. `hpp`) file?

Comment: Alternative solution: Search for all places where those erroneously included `.cpp` files exist, and fix these.

Comment: @underscore_d It's not necessarily wrong (see the end of this entry): https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl

Comment: Just because it's in the FAQ doesn't mean it's not wrong. Even if there are cases where it's 'needed', that doesn't mean it's good style. That answer to me reads like 'if you can't do something, here's a hack that lets you do it'. Anyway, probably a better way is to have a separate `cpp` file and compile them both, rather than `#include`ing, but I don't think I ever needed to do what they're talking about, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I'm trying to guard against accidental multiple includes of the file.

At least your linker will serve to throw an error message about ODR rule violations, don't worry.

> But if other files #included that .cpp file, it could be processed multiple times

Yes, it will be processed multiple times and provide multiple definitions spread over translation units that cannot be linked together anymore.

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't result in an error. Now... this might mean that I shouldn't be concerned about processing the file multiple times because the linker doesn't care, but I'd still like to know.

Comment: @taotree Maybe, provide a [MCVE] for which case the linker doesn't complain?

Comment: example: an empty file. I know that's not meaningful, but it is accurate. The answer: "the linker will tell you if it matters" is useful but doesn't directly the answer the question. If the answer is: "no, you can't" then that's fine, I just want to know.

Comment: @taotree Well, why would you want to prevent an empty file include multiple times? But, no I don't think it's possible to detect because TU's are compiled in isolation usually.

Answer (score 0):

what about using the **COUNTER** macro ? Not sure of the behaviour across projects

```
#if __COUNTER__ > 0
#error I was there already
#endif
```